# Нужна ли запятая? Сомневаюся я

Tags: запятые

Я думаю, нужна, т. к., в соответствии с Розенталём, мы ставим запятую, если перед вводным словом, тире отделённом, целые предложения, а не перечисление. Но может, правила изменились?

> Десятивопросную викторину можно хоть ежедневно проходить, а следовательно, будет больше уровень знаний(,) — значит, нужно начинать производство этих викторин.

Comment: Не надо писать: РозенталЁм.  Такой стиль вопросов не допускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам такие оформления:

***Если** десятивопросную викторину можно хоть ежедневно проходить — а следовательно, будет больше уровень знаний, — значит, нужно начинать производство этих викторин*;

***Так как** десятивопросную викторину можно хоть ежедневно проходить — а следовательно, будет больше уровень знаний, — значит, нужно начинать производство этих викторин*;

*Десятивопросную викторину можно хоть ежедневно проходить (а следовательно, будет больше уровень знаний) — значит, нужно начинать производство этих викторин*.

В первом и втором союзы ЕСЛИ..., ЗНАЧИТ и ТАК КАК..., ЗНАЧИТ, чтобы было удобно оформить вставку с тире (без них не получится, потому что некуда ставить тире, необходимое для обособления вводного слова. А если двойной союз, выделяем с двух сторон запятыми). Запятая перед вторым тире — первая запятая, обособляющая вводное слово.

В третьем вставная скобочная конструкция (без двойного союза). Тире не подходит, т. к. некуда девать третье тире, необходимое для обособления вводного слова.

**Дополнено**

И есть ещë один вариант оформления:

*Десятивопросную викторину можно хоть ежедневно проходить, а следовательно будет больше уровень знаний, — значит, нужно начинать производство этих викторин*.

Вставка обособлена запятыми; запятая после *следовательно* опускается.

Comment: Почему до тире нет запятых?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Вставка же к предыдущей части относится, а не к следующей. Нет оснований еë от первой части отделять — только от второй.